# Regex - How to prevent any string that starts with "de" but cannot use lookahead or lookbehind?

Tags: regex

I have a regex

`[a-zA-Z][a-z]`

I have to change this regex such that the regex should not accept string that starts with  "de","DE","dE" and "De" .I cannot use look behind or look ahead because my system does not support it?

Comment: What are the constraints on the rest of the input? Can you please provide sample input the does and doesn't match?

Comment: I see you've updated your regex and agree with @CinCout: it would be easier for you toi use the case-insensitive flag than maintaining both cases each time.

Comment: If you're using this in code, I'd consider using an approach without regex in this simple case. The perfomance is likely to go up.

Comment: @Alex yes, it would have  been much easier through code but there are certain restrictions because system is legacy i am not allowed to touch the code and only allowed to change the regex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a solution without a lookahead or lookbehind, but you need to be able to use groups.

The idea there is to create a sort of "honeypot" that will match your negative results and keep only the results that do interest you.

In your case, that would write:

`[dD][eE].*|(<your-regex>)`

If the proposition is `de<anything>` (case insensitive here), it will match, but group(1) will be `null`.

On the other hand, matching diZ for instance would match not match what is before the or and would therefore fall into the `group(1)`.

Finally, if the proposition doesn't start with `de` and doesn't match your regex, well, there will be no groups to get at all.

If you need to be sure that your proposition will match the whole provided string, you can update the regex thus:

`^(?:[dD][eE].*|(<your-regex>))$`

Note that `?:` is not a lookahead of any kind, it serves to mark the group as non-capturing, so that `<your-regex>` will still be captured by `group(1)` (would become `group(2)` otherwise and the capture of a group is not always a transparent operation, performance-wise).

Answer (score 2):

Simply ignore those characters:

`[a-ce-z][a-df-z][a-gi-kwxyzWZXZ]`

Make sure the flag is set to case insensitive. Also, `[a-gi-kwxyzWZXZ]` can then be modified to `[a-gi-kwxyz]`.

EDIT:

As pointed out in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65121216/regex-how-to-prevent-any-string-that-starts-with-de-but-cannot-use-lookahead/65121261?noredirect=1#comment115128776_65121261) comment, the regex here won't support other words that start with `d` but are not followed by `e`. In this case, negative lookahead is a possible solution:

`^(?!de)[a-z]+`

Comment: Nice idea, but those wouldn't take diSomething into account, because it begins with a _D_, though the start isn't _DE_.

Comment: And `[a-gi-kwxyzWZXZ]` is not the same as `[a-gi-kwxyz]|i`. Maybe it is requirement from the OP that only WXYZ can be upper case?

Comment: *If* the flag is off, *then* they are the same

Comment: @CinCout is there a way to solve the issue without changing the existing regex?

Comment: @Codemaster What do you mean? If the regex doesn't serve your purpose, the only way to make it work is to change it.

Comment: @CinCout i edited my question,the original regex which i want to edit was too big so in my previous question i did not mention this huge regex,is it possible to prevent "de" string at starting,the string should be rejext only if it starts with "d" followed by "e"

Comment: @CinCout : `[a-gi-kwxyzWZXZ]` won't match `AGI`, but `[a-gi-kwxyz]-case insensitive` will, so no, they're not the same. Please be careful when using emphasis, it might seem a tad agressive and answers may escalate from something that you may consider benign.

Comment: @Chop Which part of "If... then" is confusing?

Comment: @CinCout : Sorry, I read backwards. If the flag is off `[a-gi-kwxyzWZXZ]` will match `W` while `[a-gi-kwxyz]` won't. Still not the same.

Answer (score 0):

This matches anything *not* starting with "DE" (case insensitive, without look arounds, allowing leading whitespace):

```
^ *+(?:[^Dd].|.[^Ee])<your regex for rest of input>
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/XZU1efUGGg5wVU).

The possessive quantifier `*+` used for whitespace prevents `[^Dd]` from being allowed to match a space via backtracking, making this regex hardened against leading spaces.

Comment: This will also accept strings like "   demand" (begins with one or more whitespaces)

Comment: You could edit your answer to help the OP see how they can use it in combination with their existing regex, as it may not be obvious to everybody.

Comment: Also, the group can be made non-capturing

Comment: @CinCout both feedbacks incorporated. thank you.

Comment: @Chop it's not obvious what OP wants for the whole input, and it's not relevant for the question, but is that what you had in mind? If not, feel free to edit my answer as you like.

Comment: @Bohemian Yes, that's it. Since there are obviously other constraints, I think we need to provide the keys for how to integrate it. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an alternation excluding matching the `d` and `D` from the first character, or exclude matching the `e` as the second character.

Note that the pattern `[a-zA-Z][a-z]` matches at least 2 characters, so will the following pattern:

```
^(?:[abce-zABCE-Z][a-z]|[a-zA-Z][a-df-z]).*
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[abce-zABCE-Z][a-z]` Match a char a-zA-Z without `d` and `D` followed by a lowercase char a-z
  - `|` or
  - `[a-zA-Z][a-df-z]` Match a char a-zA-Z followed by a lowercase chars a-z without `e`
- `)` Close non capture grou
- `.*` Match 0+ times any char except a newline

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HTb1y3/1)

Another option is to use word boundaries `\b` instead of an anchor `^`

```
\b(?:[abce-zABCE-Z][a-z]|[a-zA-Z][a-df-z])[a-zA-Z]*\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FVWxj5/1)